# Flutter auto generate keys of json/arb file to code

Tags: flutter, dart, internationalization, build-runner

I am using the [Flutter Intl](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13666-flutter-intl) plugin to generate an arb (JSON) file for internationalization. Content of file intl_en.arb is JSON like this:

```
{
  "msg1": "message..",
  "msg2": "message..",
  "msg3": "message.."
}
```

I want to auto-generate all the keys of the JSON to class. The content of the class should look like this:

```
class AllText {
  static const String msg1 = 'msg1';
  static const String msg2 = 'msg2';
  static const String msg3 = 'msg3';
}
```

So I can use `GetX` internationalization like this:

```
Text(AllText.msg1.tr)
```

Is there a plugin to generate the class like this from the arb file?

(I don't want to use Intl, just need it to generate JSON file so I can use it in `GetX`)

Comment: Check this link "https://app.quicktype.io/"

Answer (score 0):

**Update Jun 22nd:**

For the generation from the arb file to class, you are looking for this package `flutter_localizations`. The config is straightforward and guided in the [official documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization#setting-up) on i18n.

If you are using Android Studio/ IntelliJ IDEA like me, there's a package called [flutter_intl](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13666-flutter-intl) (Check [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=localizely.flutter-intl) if you use VS Code) that allows you to generate the class in a few clicks.

---

For i18n integration with `GetX`, simply copy the content of the `arb` files to a `Map`, then config it as below:

For example, here's an `arb` file containing the keys:

```
{
  "msg1": "message",
  "msg2": "message",
  "msg3": "message"
}
```

Declare variables representing your desired locales:

```
const Map<String, String> en = {
  "msg1": "message",
  "msg2": "message",
  "msg3": "message"
};

const Map<String, String> fr = {
  "msg1": "message_other",
  "msg2": "message_other",
  "msg3": "message_other"
};
```

Then, create a class extending `Translations` from `GetX`

```
class LocalizationService extends Translations {

  // Default locale
  static final locale = Locale('en', 'US');

  // fallback locale saves the day when the locale gets in trouble
  static final fallbackLocale = Locale('fr', 'FR');

  // Your supported language here
  static final langs = [
    'English',
    'France',
  ];

  // Supported locales (same order as above)
  static final locales = [
    Locale('en', 'US'),
    Locale('fr', 'FR'),
  ];

  // Keys and their translations
  // Translations are defined with `en` and `fr` variable above
  @override
  Map<String, Map<String, String>> get keys => {
        'en_US': en,
        'tr_TR': fr,
      };


  // Use the following method to update your locale
  // Gets locale from language and updates the locale
  void changeLocale(String lang) {
    final locale = _getLocaleFromLanguage(lang);
    Get.updateLocale(locale);
  }

  // Finds language in `langs` list and returns it as Locale
  Locale _getLocaleFromLanguage(String lang) {
    for (int i = 0; i < langs.length; i++) {
      if (lang == langs[i]) return locales[i];
    }
    return Get.locale;
  }
}
```

Finally, define the locale in your `GetMaterialApp`:

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
      locale: LocalizationService.locale,
      fallbackLocale: LocalizationService.fallbackLocale,
      translations: LocalizationService(),
    );
  }
}
```

Use the locale as below:

```
Text('msg1'.tr) // The `tr` extension is from `GetX` as well
```

Comment: The point is to generate the class contains all keys so when you use it, you know the key is correct, no worry about typo. Not how to use GetX.

Comment: @dante Updated my answer, I think it's what you're looking for